# Update query not executing in loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I don't know what is the problem with this code. The values are coming fine in the array, but when I execute the query nothing, gets updated.

```
<?php 
  $loop=0;
  while($loop< sizeof($stararray)){
    $starsquery="update updatedstars set id='$distcodes[$loop]' ,stars='$stararray[$loop]'";
    //$starsquery="insert into updatedstars (id,stars) values ( '$distcodes[$loop]','$stararray[$loop]')";
    echo $starsquery;
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $starsquery);
    $loop++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: You do realize you are updating every single row in your table?  Beyond that, what debugging have you tried?  Error message?

Comment: I have to make $distcode unique so when i execute the code with unique constraints on $distcode in database it gives me this error:

update updatedstars set id='11' ,stars='1'Error: Duplicate entry '11' for key 'id'

Comment: the insert statements work fine which is commented in the code but i want to execute the update statement because i have to update database entries.

Comment: So `WHERE id=...` not `SET id=...`...

Comment: I am sorry i did n't understand, please explain @Devon

Comment: @Wiz read up on update statements.  An update without a WHERE argument will affect every single row.  You obviously don't want that and you don't want to SET the id, you want to update the row WHERE the id matches.

Comment: Yes i knew it before, but i was updating the whole table, but i have found another way around according to my requirements Thanks :)

Comment: @Wiz - If you've solved the problem and one of the answers to your question helped, please mark that answer as accepted to help future visitors to SO see how to solve this same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your SQL statement. Your PHP code will function just fine.

You are executing the SQL statement

```
UPDATE `updatedstars` SET `id` = SOME_ID, `stars` = SOME_STARS
```

This is **not** the SQL statement that you had indicated you wanted based on the `while` loop that you are running. The above statement will update every row in your `updatedstars` table to the values in that query. That's likely **not good** and **not your intended design**.

What you want to do is to limit the update to a single row, namely the one with the proper `id` value.

Your query should be

```
UPDATE `updatedstars` SET `stars` = SOME_STARS WHERE `id` = SOME_ID
```

In your PHP code, that's

```
$starsquery="update updatedstars set stars='$stararray[$loop]' where id='$distcodes[$loop]'";
```

I'd strongly suggest reading up on [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html), [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) queries for MySQL.